# how to use parameter display output as a value to calculate this value in other issue?

Tags: cognos

I have made a parameterDisplay to calculate someData to get the timezone for the target and actual salestargets, then the report shows me this value example (100%).

So now I need to use this 100% to multiply it in another thing example (100%  * actual target).. so how can I use this output in another calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the query.
2. Drag data item from the toolbox.
3. Assuming your prompt name is prmSalesTarget, then in the expression write ?prmSalesTarget? * ActualTarget.
4. Give meaningfull name to the data item and drag it into report